# Image Processing using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am reading a fits file to a matrix 'I' using the `fitsread` command. Matrix 'I' is a 1024*1024 matrix of type double. It's value ranges from - 11 to 440.678. My question is

1. The MATLAB toolbox specifies the range of double from 0 to 1, then why is it my matrix has such a large variation?
2. When I plot a histogram of the matrix 'I' using `imhist`, the range of x axis varies from 0 to 1. Also there are hardly any points plotted. Why is the range for `imhist` 0 to 1?

Comment: Usually the values from 0 to 1 are converted versions of the matrix from 0 to 255 to create the RGB scale.

Comment: What is the `info.Image.DataType`  when you type `info = fitsinfo('[YourFileName]');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Range of `double` is not from 0 to 1. It is the range for displaying double images.
2. `imhist` function uses the range [0,1] for `double` type images by default, but you can change it by adding an extra parameter imhist(I,n) where n is the number of bins(You can use 452 in your case).